# How add ColumnChart to DockLayoutPanel in Java?

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I have code writen on Java

```
public class MyClass implements EntryPoint {
public void onModuleLoad() {

    // Create a callback to be called when the visualization API
    // has been loaded.
    Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();

            // Create a Dock Panel
            DockLayoutPanel dockLayoutPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
            dockLayoutPanel.setStyleName("dockpanel");
            dockLayoutPanel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("border", "solid lightblue 4px");

            // Add text all around
            dockLayoutPanel.addNorth(new HTML("This is the first north component."), 2);
            //dockPanel.addEast(col.asWidget(), 1);
            dockLayoutPanel.addWest(new HTML("This is the west component."), 3);

            VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
            ColumnChart col = new ColumnChart(createTable(), createOptions());
            col.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(col));
            verticalPanel.add(col);
            dockLayoutPanel.add(verticalPanel);                                             

            rp.add(dockLayoutPanel);
        }
    };

    // Load the visualization api, passing the onLoadCallback to be called
    // when loading is done.
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback,
            ColumnChart.PACKAGE);
}
```

}

Help me, peoples!)) How add ColunnChart in DockLayoutPanel? In this code I add ColumnChart to VerticalPanel,then add VerticalPanel to dockLayoutPanel, and then dockLayoutPanel add to RootLayoutPanel. But ERROR.

Comment: What ERROR are you getting. Please share few line of stack trace.

Comment: I debug this code and after line "Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {" proceeds to line "VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback,
            ColumnChart.PACKAGE);" and the method never sets

Comment: Can you try it without using `VisualizationUtils` as suggested in my post?

Comment: `VerticalPanel` and `ColumnChart` creation are moved into `ChartLoader.loadApi()` method and added `verticalPanel` in `dockLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        ColumnChart col = new ColumnChart();
        col.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(col));
        verticalPanel.add(col);
        col.draw(createTable(), createOptions());
        dockLayoutPanel.add(verticalPanel); 
    }
});
```

instead of

```
        VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        ColumnChart col = new ColumnChart(createTable(), createOptions());
        col.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(col));
        verticalPanel.add(col);
        dockLayoutPanel.add(verticalPanel);
```

---

-- EDIT --

Complete sample code

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();

    // Create a Dock Panel
    final DockLayoutPanel dockLayoutPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    dockLayoutPanel.setStyleName("dockpanel");
    dockLayoutPanel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("border", "solid lightblue 4px");

    // Add text all around
    dockLayoutPanel.addNorth(new HTML("This is the first north component."), 2);
    // dockPanel.addEast(col.asWidget(), 1);
    dockLayoutPanel.addWest(new HTML("This is the west component."), 3);

    ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
    chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
            ColumnChart col = new ColumnChart();
            verticalPanel.add(col);
            drawChart(col);
            dockLayoutPanel.add(verticalPanel);
        }
    });

    rp.add(dockLayoutPanel);
} 

private void drawChart(ColumnChart chart) {
    // Prepare the data
    DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Density");
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Copper");
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Silver");
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Gold");
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Platinum");

    dataTable.addRows(1);

    dataTable.setValue(0, 0, "");
    dataTable.setValue(0, 1, 8.94);
    dataTable.setValue(0, 2, 10.49);
    dataTable.setValue(0, 3, 19.30);
    dataTable.setValue(0, 4, 21.45);

    // Draw the chart
    ColumnChartOptions options = ColumnChartOptions.create();
    options.setVAxis(VAxis.create("Density"));
    options.setHAxis(HAxis.create("Metel"));

    String[] colors = new String[] { "#b87333", "silver", "gold", "#e5e4e2" };
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        ColumnChartSeries series = ColumnChartSeries.create();
        series.setColor(colors[i]);
        options.setSeries(i, series);
    }
    options.setTitle("Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3");

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

Add below line in your `gwt.xml` file

```
  <inherits name="com.googlecode.gwt.charts.Charts"/>
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this one? Its working for me without using `VisualizationUtils`.

Comment: I corrected my code as you have advised me and add line <inherits name="com.googlecode.gwt.charts.Charts"/>  in the my XML definition file, but text can be seen now on the screen, and no chart

Comment: Have you tried calling `draw()` method as suggested in my post.

Comment: Also tried `chartLoader.loadApi()` without using `VisualizationUtils`? Let me know if still not working then I will post my sample code to you.

Comment: I tried chartLoader.loadApi() without using VisualizationUtils, as you have advised me. But no chart on the screen

Comment: I edit my code, but no chart on the screen. Then I commenting out line "dockLayoutPanel.setStyleName("dockpanel"); " -> Refresh -> And 1sec I saw chart, but then chart disappeared again

Comment: I don't know what have you defined in this style. Why you don't try my sample code first as an separate application.

Comment: It is understand, but if I don`t use style - anyway I do not see the chart now on the screen

Comment: Let me summarize the changes that I have done in my code: 1. I have removed line `col.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(col));` 2. Replacing `ColumnChart col = new ColumnChart(createTable(), createOptions());` with `ColumnChart col = new ColumnChart(); col.draw(createTable(), createOptions());` 3. Do not using `VisualizationUtils` 4. Using `ChartLoader.loadApi` 5. I do not have any style `dockpanel` defined.

Comment: May be there is some issue with `createTable` and `createOptions`. Please share the code for these also to analyze.

Comment: Yes you are right. I fix and have good result. Remained one problem. Nope borders

Comment: I want to show the borders, but om my screen no borders.

Comment: Not at all, my friend. I feel happy.

Comment: Are you talking about the blue borders that is shown in above snapshot?

Comment: Use css `broder : 4px solid lightblue;` defiend in `dockpanel` OR try this in code `dockLayoutPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderColor("lightblue"); dockLayoutPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(4, Unit.PX); dockLayoutPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID);` instead of `setProperty("border", "solid lightblue 4px");`

Comment: Yes, there are the external borders and internal havent... Why is it interesting?

Comment: Define the borders for `HTML` components that is added in `DockLayoutPanel`. It will solve your problem. You can set border-bottom/left/right/top also as per requirement.

Comment: For e.g         `HTML html=new HTML("This is the first north component.");
        html.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("border", "solid lightblue 4px");
        dockLayoutPanel.addNorth(html, 2);`

Comment: Braj, you're a genius. Very big thank you!)) My skype: dumko27. I would be glad if you will add me

Comment: I will add you, once Skype is installed on my system. :)

Comment: Do you know how to make and addEast addWest evenly so they do not overlap each abuse are if you increase the size?

Comment: Use `Overflow.VISIBLE` property `.getElement().getStyle().setOverflow(Overflow.VISIBLE)`